# Disable email alerts when modules are out of date

Tags: updating

How can I disable Drupal's email alerts when modules or core are out of date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to http://mysite.com/admin/reports/updates/settings, and remove all the email addresses from the *E-mail addresses to notify when updates are available* textarea:

[image]

Just to highlight the pertinent of the description on that field:

> If blank, no emails will be sent.